# How to get Review & Ratings by Product Id In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, review

I am trying the below code but not working can you please help what i am doing wrong

```
class classname implements classnameInterface
{

          protected $subscriberFactory;
            protected $reviewFactory;
            protected $storeManager;
            protected $product;


      public function __construct(


    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager


) {
    $this->subscriberFactory= $subscriberFactory;
    $this->reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;



}

    public function review($reviewId) {


 $this->reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, 1);
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();

    return $ratingSummary;

    }




}
```

Should i need to $product Declaration anywhere ?

Comment: Do you want to display reviews on product page?

Comment: @Jai : no i want to send data in response via rest Api I am able to return summary ratings but i want description ,label ,count

Comment: Please have a look in to the following link,  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205582/how-to-display-star-rating-summary/205647

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be perfect may be you are missing something.

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');

    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
```

load `$product` object somewhere before getEntitySummary line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);
$collection = $rating->create()->addStoreFilter($currentStoreId)->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)->addEntityFilter('product',$product->getId())->setDateOrder();
$reviewlist = $collection->getData();
$review_total_text = sizeof($reviewlist).' reviews';
$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
?>
<div class="rating-summary item" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" >
    <div class="rating-result" title="<?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%">
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="100">
        <span style="width:<?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%">
            <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product_review_div_list" style="display: none;">
        <?php
        foreach($reviewlist as $_review){
            $review_id = $_review['review_id'];
        ?>
        <div class="rating-summary item" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" >
            <div class="rating-result" title="<?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%">
                <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
                <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="100">
                <span style="width:<?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%">
                    <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
            <p><?php echo $_review['title'];?></p>
            <p><?php echo $_review['detail'];?></p>
            <p><?php echo $_review['nickname'];?>           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $_review['created_at'];?>   &nbsp;</p>
            <hr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```