# How to display star rating summary

Tags: product, frontend, magento2.2, product-page, ratings

I have **removed reviews tab** and placed the form in a **popup modal**.

**Now I have displayed all the reviews posted by the customer about the particular product and I have displayed the Rating summary for the Product**.

Now I need to **get Rating** for each customer and **display in the following format**  for each reviews in frontend.
Please Provide me a solution to add star rating for each reviews.

[image]

This is my collection class I have displayed in frontend like below

[image]

For reference

**Block file**

```
<?php

namespace XXX\YYY\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Collection extends Template
{


    protected $_coreRegistry;

    protected $_reviewsColFactory;


    protected $_reviewFactory;
    protected $_voteFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,\Magento\Review\Model\Rating\Option\VoteFactory $voteFactory, \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_reviewsColFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
         $this->_voteFactory = $voteFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getProductId()
    {

        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        return $product ? $product->getId() : null;
    }


    public function getCollectionSize()
    {
        $collection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                )->addStatusFilter(
                        \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
                )->addEntityFilter(
                'product', $this->getProductId()
        );

        return $collection->getSize();
    }

    public function getAllreviews()
    {
        $collection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                )->addStatusFilter(
                        \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
                )->addEntityFilter(
                'product', $this->getProductId()
        );

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getRatingSummary()
    {
        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
        return $ratingSummary;
    }

}
```

**abc.phtml**

```
<div id="customer-reviews" class="customer-reviews">
    <?php $reviews = $block->getAllreviews(); ?>

    <span><b><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Rating summary : ') ?></b></span><?php echo $rating = $block->getRatingSummary(); ?><br>

    <div id ="reviews" class="reviews"> <span><b><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Customer Reviews') ?></b></span><br>
        <?php foreach ($reviews as $review): ?>           
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Customer Name : ') ?></span><?php echo $review->getNickname(); ?><br>
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Review : ') ?></span><?php echo $review->getDetail(); ?><br>
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date : ') ?></span><?php echo $review->getCreatedAt(); ?><br>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are going to show it in your way then you must write custom code, js and css. If you have the rating summay then it is not difficult to implement. Is your question is just about displaying stars for rating summary i.e. show 4 highlighted stars for review summary of 80.

Comment: Yes. How to display star rating summary

Comment: I have to look for magento way. but you can write your own js , css make your own star.

Comment: But I need to get star rating for each review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reviews, the star rating summary is displayed based on the percentage of the  rating vote provided in a particular review. Using this rating-vote-percentage, the the star symbol is highlighted using the width property of the span element.

To get the vote percentage, loop your review collection and for each review, get the vote percentage as follows.

```
foreach ($reviews as $review) {
if (count($review->getRatingVotes())) { 
    foreach ($review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote) { 
        $rating_vote[] =  $_vote->getPercent();
    }
}
else
    $rating_vote = null;
}
```

Using the `$rating_vote_percentage` value, you have to apply styles in your own way to indicate the star rating.

Use this code in your abc.phtml file accordingly.

To display the star rating for each review, just replace the whole code in your abc.phtml file with the below code.

```
<div id="customer-reviews" class="customer-reviews">
<?php $reviews = $block->getAllreviews(); ?>

<span><b><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Rating summary : ') ?></b></span><?php echo $rating = $block->getRatingSummary(); ?><br>

<div id ="reviews" class="reviews"> <span><b><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Customer Reviews') ?></b></span><br>
    <?php foreach ($reviews as $review): ?>  
    <?php
        if (count($review->getRatingVotes())) { 
            foreach ($review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote) { 
                $rating_vote =  $_vote->getPercent();
            }
        }
        else
            $rating_vote = 0;

    ?>      
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Customer Name : ') ?></span><?php echo $review->getNickname(); ?><br>
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Review : ') ?></span><?php echo $review->getDetail(); ?><br>
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date : ') ?></span><?php echo $review->getCreatedAt(); ?><br>

        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Rating : ') ?></span>
        <div class="rating-result" >
            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content = "100"/>
            <span style="width:<?php echo $rating_vote; ?>%">
                <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo $rating_vote; ?>%</span>
            </span>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where I need to put this code

Comment: It depends on, how you are accessing the review collection. If you are using custom block, then you have to place this code inside your custom block function. If you are loading the review collection in your popup modal, then you have to place the above code in your popup modal .

Comment: I have updated my code Please refer @MGento

Comment: Based on the code you have posted, you should place this code  inside your abc.phtml file

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: I will update my answer with complete code as per your requirement.

Comment: You can verify it if you analyze the Magento core functionality. In Luma they have used the same method. Please have a look in to the core file   vendor\magento\module-review\view\frontend\templates\product\view\list.phtml

Comment: It shows rating as 0% for each reviews

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70158/discussion-between-jayashree-and-mgento).

Comment: ok, sure.  First lets make sure we have the rating votes for the particular product review.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70171/discussion-between-sri-and-mgento).

Comment: are you getting ratings stars also actually i am trying to show stars

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use bellow code in your phtml file **You should not use the ObjectManager directly!**

```
<?php
$productId = 'your_product_id';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$storeManager  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
$reviewCount = $product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
?>
<?php if($ratingSummary){ ?>
<div class="product-reviews-summary short">
    <div class="rating-summary">
        <div title="<?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%" class="rating-result">
            <span style="width:<?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%"><span><?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews-actions">
        <?php echo __('('.$reviewCount.') Reviews'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How I get a product's star rating. Very easy to implement throughout a site.

```
<?php $_rating = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->load($_product->getId()); ?>

<?php if ($_rating['rating_summary']) {?>
  <div class="ratings">
      <div class="rating-box">
         <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_rating['rating_summary']; ?>%"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```